# Is there a way to make async function sync?

Tags: javascript

I have code like this.

```js
async function doAsync(count){
  //external function I need to use
  count++;
  console.log("async count is "+ count );
  return await count;
}
 
function makeSyncChain(i){
  //my chain that I could change
  i=doAsync(i);
  return i;
}

let val=0;
console.log("sync count is " + makeSyncChain(val));
```

so like at the example, I have sync chain and one of the chain function is async, is there a way to make async function working in sync chain?

Comment: It is synchronous if you don't use await. In your case the "async" prefix is fully redundant.

Comment: No. Using async almost always implies needing to wait for something in the future to arrive. I say *"almost always"* because your example does not. Nothing you are actually doing requires using async

Comment: An async function returns a promise so you need to handle that promise resolving to access what you want

Comment: Thanks for answers, but async function is not my function, I cannot change it,
As an option, I'm trying to use async chain with promises, but it returns me promise when I need value((

Comment: Why not use top level `await`? Just `const count = await doAsync(value);` then  `console.log("count is " + count);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct solution must be:

```js
async function doAsync(count){
  //external function I need to use
  count++;
  console.log("async count is "+ count );
  return await count;
}

let val=0;
console.log("sync count is " + (await doAsync(val)));
```

But in wrong key may be written as (and yes **it won't work**, it will just **hang the browser**):

```js
async function doAsync(count){
  //external function I need to use
  count++;
  console.log("async count is "+ count );
  return await count;
}
 
function makeSyncChain(i){
  //my chain that I could change
  let isDone = false;
  let result;
  doAsync(i).then(r => {
    result = r;
  }).finally(() => {
    isDone = true;
  });
  while (!isDone);
  return result;
}

let val=0;
console.log("sync count is " + makeSyncChain(val));
```